# I m not able to start eclipse classic version 4.2 on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, eclipse

I m new to android development. After I click to launch eclipse it shows an error:

> "An error has occurred. See the log file  D:\JAVA\workspace.metadata.log."

When I checked log file it says *(I m putting only last log)*

> "!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-16 17:44:13.991
>   !MESSAGE Application error
>   !STACK 1
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.processHierarchy(E4Workbench.java:172)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.init(E4Workbench.java:118)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.(E4Workbench.java:69)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:302)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:554)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>   "

Comment: Same here, eclipse would no longer start after the 4.2 SR1 upgrade. No solution yet, though.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04. Any hints on how to solve this are welcome.